# Can't get imageUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

i try to upload and get image in webapi net core but when i get imageUrl it don't run even i use app.UseStaticFile()
In Program.cs I use app.UseStaticFiles();

Code Upload and get Image

```
[HttpPut("UploadImage")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile formFile, string productId)
{
    APIResponse response = new APIResponse();
    try
    {
        string Filepath = GetFilePath(productId);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Filepath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Filepath);
        }
        string imagepath = Filepath + "\\" + productId + "png";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagepath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(imagepath);
        }
        using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create(imagepath))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            response.ResponseCode = 200;
            response.Result = "pass";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return Ok(response);
}

[HttpGet("GetImage")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage(string productId)
{
    string imageUrl = string.Empty;
    string hostUrl = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.PathBase}";
    try
    {
        string Filepath = GetFilePath(productId);
        string imagepath = Filepath + "\\" + productId + "png";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagepath))
        {
            imageUrl = hostUrl + "/Upload/Product/" + productId + "/" + productId + ".png";
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return Ok(imageUrl);
}
[NonAction]
public string GetFilePath(string productId)
{
    return this.environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\Product\\" + productId;
}
```

This is wwwroot
[wwwroot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CIm2.png)

This is result
[swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSLLp.png)
[Image not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y24p.png)

Please help me with this problem!!!

Comment: try setting string imagepath = Path.Combine(Filepath, productId + ".png");, make sure image path is correct and image is present at the path. set the mime type while returning image return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagepath), "image/png");

Answer (score 0):

In your wwwroot folder, image is named as - '001png' (No dot between 001 and extension) and in your swagger, you are getting '001.png'

Could you please check that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try above answers and also change code while setting the imagePath

Old :
string imagepath = Filepath + "\" + productId + "png";
new :
string imagepath = Filepath + "\" + productId + **".png";**